# How to configure apache superset to connect keycloak based oauth2 enabled trino source and auto open authentication url in browser?

Tags: keycloak, apache-superset, trino

I have configured oauth2 authentication in Trino using keycloak.
Then I am running Trino queries through Apache superset.
Whenever I am connecting to data source (Trino) through apache superset, it gives authentication url in logs like shown below.

```
2023-04-13 21:17:27,947:INFO:superset.sql_lab:Query 28: Set query to 'running'
Open the following URL in browser for the external authentication:
https://vm1:8443/oauth2/token/initiate/6a8914b28fd1f6a337538ef75c14f7f9c9f5d74a5c15ee1c3cfa49ad52a73731
```

Every time I need to copy this URL from logs and open in browser manually.
Checking logs for authentication URL is not possible for each user.

How to configure apache superset to connect keycloak based oauth2 enabled trino source and auto open authentication url in browser?